# Json output using Mongo Compass issue

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, mongodb-compass

I need to export the data from a Dev MongoDB collection and deploy the data into another environment(UAT) collection. I was using MongoDB compass Export Collection tool to output the documents as Json format and then import the Json file using the GUI add data tool, it was working fine without a problem.

I will need to script everything so it can be run from command line instead of manually using the tool then I noticed that the json format generated from the Export Collection tool has changed some data type. When I use insertMany command to insert the output Json file. It will have errors. For example, I have some date field, the output generated from Export Collection tool converted them to
"$date": {
"$numberLong": "1650603600000"
}
Instead, it should be format like ISODate("2022-06-02T05:00:00.000Z").

It wasn't causing issue using the GUI to add the data using this format but if I use the command insertMany and then insert the Json format, the data will not be date anymore. Any way to get around this problem?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongodump to avoid conversion to json. You can read more about extended json date format here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date

Comment: Thanks Alex. I am getting errors when trying to run mongoexport using compass MongoSH. clone(t={}){const r=t.loc||{};return e({loc:new Position("line"in r?r.line:this.loc.line,"column"in r?r.column:...<omitted>...)} could not be cloned. Do you know whether mongoexport supported in Compass MongoSH?

Comment: How exactly are you using mongosh to export the collection? mongoexport is a CLI utility from mongodb tools package.

Comment: I ran the following command when opening the Compass Mongosh screen:
mongoexport --db test --collection mytestcollectoin --out /data/dump/mytestcollection.json

Comment: I also noticed that even I manually change the format of the Json file to date format, when I used insertMany, the data insert to the database is still the format of: "UpdDate": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1654146000000"
    }
  }. How can I avoid this ? My database is Azure CosmosDB (MongAPI) V3.6. I don't know whether that could be related.

Comment: mongoexport https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/ is a **command line tool** Command line is a cmd, console, terminal, depending on your operation system. mongosh https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/ is a mongodb IDLE.  If you run mongoexport in mongosh you should get something like "mongoexport is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your date:

From this:

```
"$date": { "$numberLong": "1650603600000" }
```

To this:

```
new Date("1650603600000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please download MongoDB Shell and run it on the terminal (not on MongoDB Compass), and you will get it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).